# How does New York Times get their icon next to the "just now" time indicator on their Glass Timeline cards?

Tags: google-mirror-api

I'm building a Google Glass app and notice that New York Times has their little New York Times icon to the right of the "Just Now" time indicator in the lower right of each card. How are they doing this? Is this something I can upload in the API Console, or do I have to manually add this as HTML in each HTML page card? And how do you do it in the Glass browser? I don't see any examples in the templates. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

These icons are set up during the launch process for Glassware. Follow the [steps on this page](https://developers.google.com/glass/distributing/index) to submit your Glassware for launch review.

The little icon in the lower right corner that you see is called the source icon. Source icons are specified when you launch your Glassware and set up higher quota.

Comment: I see the timestamp, but no logo for the app with the Timestamp. It just says "Just Now" with the card and no icon next to it like New York Times has.

Comment: Oooh I completely misread your question. Let me update my answer.

Comment: I'm currently setting this up for a local news organization (top 15 in the USA) - any chance I can get on the list? :-)

Comment: Any idea when this will be available to Glass Explorer experimenting with app writing (both Mirror API and native)?

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the fact that the submission form is now up :) https://developers.google.com/glass/distributing/index