# Set the contact Icon for a Google Glass contact

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I notice the contacts for other pieces of glassware have an icon before the displayName, ie the twitter "bird" or "g+" icon for Google+. I'd like to do the same for my glassware, but I don't see any way to do this in the documentation, however.

On a whim, I attempted to add an "iconUrl" to the contact when inserting it (similar to how menu items work), but that didn't seem to do it.

Am I missing something? Is the documentation missing something?

Comment: You'll have to wait for someone from Google to respond, but I am guessing the answer will be similar to this, meaning you can't add that kind of icon - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950861/how-does-new-york-times-get-their-icon-next-to-the-just-now-time-indicator-on

Answer (score 1):

The small icon that appears next to the contact's `displayName` is taken from Google's server: this happens when the Glassware is officially "launched".

We are still working on the release form and hope to have it ready for all explorers soon! In the meantime, keep exploring and share your ideas on the community forum.